# Show that a disjoint family $(I_\lambda)_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ of not degenerate intervals of $\Bbb{R}$ is at most denumerable

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I found this problem in a book:

> Let $(I_\lambda)_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ be a not degenerate family of disjoint sets of $\Bbb{R}$. Prove that $card((I_\lambda)) \leq \aleph_0$ (That is, the family is at most denumerable

I have proved it by taking a rational number $q_\lambda$ such that $\forall \lambda \in \Lambda: q_\lambda \in I_\lambda \cap \Bbb{Q}$. Such $q_\lambda$ exists because $\Bbb{Q}$ is dense in every non degenerate interval of  $\Bbb{R}$. Then I've built the function $f:(I_\lambda)_{\lambda \in \Lambda} \rightarrow \Bbb{Q}$ such that $I_\lambda \longmapsto q_\lambda$. The function is obviously injective because $\forall \lambda_1, \lambda_2 \in \Lambda, \lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2, I_{\lambda_1} \cap I_{\lambda_2} = \emptyset$ by hypothesis, hence showing that $card((I_\lambda)_{\lambda \in \Lambda}) \leq card(\Bbb{Q}) = \aleph_0$

<del>But now I'm wondering whether the hypothesis are too restrictive: I can replace the *disjoint* part of the theorem with the following $$\forall \lambda_1, \lambda_2 \in \Lambda, \lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2, I_{\lambda_1} \cap I_{\lambda_2} \text{is non degenerate interval of $\Bbb{R}$}$$</del>

**EDIT2: neither of the weaker hypothesis below works. See accepted answer and comments**

<del>EDIT: **As pointed out by JDMan4444 and Hagen von Eitzen this weaker condition does not hold** but then I produced another condition weaker than the one given in the theorem but stronger than the one I've given:</del>

$$\forall \lambda_1, \lambda_2 \in \Lambda, \lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2, I_{\lambda_1} \nsubseteq I_{\lambda_2} \; \text{and} \; I_{\lambda_1} \cap I_{\lambda_2} \text{is not degenerate interval of $\Bbb{R}$}$$

And the proof would be similar, but the $q_\lambda$ is taken from the interval that is unique to each set.

---

<del>*Actually, while I'm writing this question, I'm thinking that if we have a family of non degenerate intervals of $\Bbb{R}$ defined with the weaker hypothesis, we could define another family $$(J_\lambda)_{\lambda \in \Lambda} = \bigcap_{\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2 \in \Lambda} (\Bbb{R} \smallsetminus (I_{\lambda_1} \cap I_{\lambda_2}))$$ 
of disjoint intervals of $\Bbb{R}$ which is denumerable as proven above... I don't know if this helps nor if it is correct*</del>

Comment: But: For $\lambda>0$ let $I_\lambda=(0,\lambda)$, Then for $\lambda_1\ne\lambda_2$, $I_{\lambda_1}\cap I_{\lambda_2}$ is a non-degenerate interal.

Comment: "every non degenerate interval of $\mathbb R$ is dense in $\mathbb Q$". Rather, $\mathbb Q$ is dense in every non degenerate interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can weaken the hypothesis as you have suggested.

Take $\Lambda=\mathbb{R}^{+}$, the non-negative reals, and define $I_{\lambda}=(-\infty,\lambda)$ for $\lambda\in\Lambda$. Pairwise intersections are non-degenerate, and there are uncountably many of them.

As I was typing this a comment was made with the same basic idea.

As per the comment below and edit above, we can define $I_\lambda=(-1/\lambda,1+\lambda^2)$ for $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, the positive reals, showing that the issue is not that the intervals are nested.

Comment: I didn't think of it... but what if we weaken it by saying that $\forall \lambda_1, \lambda_2 \in \Lambda, \lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2, I_{\lambda_1} \nsubseteq I_{\lambda_2}$? The problem should be solved, but it is a more restrictive hypothesis that the one I've given.

Comment: @LuxGiammi I have added work that I think shows that this new hypothesis is still not strong enough.

Comment: Ok. That was just an idea that came up to my mind and I just would have liked to check whether it was correct. Thanks a lot for your help. :-)

Comment: @LuxGiammi You are welcome!